# Kleene realizability in Peano arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, constructive-mathematics, realizability

For completeness of MathOverflow and for clarity of the question, I will first recall a few things, including the the definition of Kleene realizability: experts can jump directly to the question below.

For natural numbers $n$ and first-order formulae $\varphi$ of Heyting arithmetic, the formula “$n$ realizes $\varphi$” is defined by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$ by:

- for atomic $\varphi$, “$n$ realizes $\varphi$” simply means $\varphi$ [is true],
- $n$ realizes $\varphi\land\psi$ iff $n=\langle p,q\rangle$ (some fixed primitive recursive bijective pairing function $\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}$) where $p$ realizes $\varphi$ and $q$ realizes $\psi$,
- $n$ realizes $\varphi\lor\psi$ iff $n=\langle 0,p\rangle$ where $p$ realizes $\varphi$ or $n=\langle 1,q\rangle$ where $q$ realizes $\psi$,
- $n$ realizes $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ iff for each $p$ which realizes $\varphi$, the value $\{n\}(p)$ (of the $n$-th partial recursive function applied to $p$) is defined and realizes $\psi$,
- $n$ realizes $\exists x.\psi(x)$ iff $n=\langle k,q\rangle$ where $q$ realizes $\psi(k)$ (meaning the substitution for $x$ in $\psi$ of the explicit term representing the integer $k$),
- $n$ realizes $\forall x.\psi(x)$ iff for each $k$, the value $\{n\}(k)$ is defined and realizes $\psi(k)$.

This in turn defines a new first-order formula of Heyting arithmetic which we can denote, say, $n\mathbin{\mathbf{r}}\varphi$.

Now I understand that (Dragalin and Troelstra independently proved that) for all $\varphi$,

1. $\mathsf{HA} + \mathrm{ECT}_0 \vdash (\varphi \Leftrightarrow \exists n.(n\mathbin{\mathbf{r}}\varphi))$
2. $\mathsf{HA} + \mathrm{ECT}_0 \vdash \varphi$ if and only if $\mathsf{HA} \vdash \exists n.(n\mathbin{\mathbf{r}}\varphi)$

where $\mathsf{HA}$ denotes Heyting arithmetic and $\mathrm{ECT}_0$ some statement (the “extended Church thesis”) which I won't copy because it's not really germane to my question but which says informally that every relation on an almost negatively defined domain contains a partial recursive function defined on that domain; note that $\mathrm{ECT}_0$ is classically refutable.

Furthermore, in (2) (well, trivially in (1) also), $\mathsf{HA}$ can be replaced by $\mathsf{HA} + \mathrm{MP}$, where $\mathrm{MP}$ (“Markov's principle”) is the (classically tautological) $(\forall x.(\psi(x)\lor\neg\psi(x))) \Rightarrow ((\neg\neg\exists x.\psi(x))\Rightarrow \exists x.\psi(x))$.

To paraphrase, $\mathsf{HA} + \mathrm{ECT}_0$ axiomatizes the set of formulae provably realizable in $\mathsf{HA}$, and $\mathsf{HA} + \mathrm{MP} + \mathrm{ECT}_0$ axiomatizes the set of formulae provably realizable in $\mathsf{HA} + \mathrm{MP}$.

This leads me to ask:

> **Question:** what can be said about the set of formulae $\varphi$ such that $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \exists n.(n\mathbin{\mathbf{r}}\varphi)$, where $\mathsf{PA}$ denotes Peano arithmetic (i.e., Heyting arithmetic plus the excluded middle)?  In other words, what are the set of formulae provably realizable in Peano arithmetic?  Can they be axiomatized?

Comment: A follow-up question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463177/what-is-the-theory-of-statements-with-a-provably-bounded-realizer-according-t

Comment: Just a comment: For the clauses regarding disjunction and existential quantification, it's quite important that the pairing function is **not** some standard primitive-recursive bijection. Instead, we should pair two numbers $x_1,x_2$ by the index of some canonical Turing machine which on input $i$ terminates with $x_i$. Else the soundness theorem "if HA proves a formula $\varphi$, there is a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that HA proves $n \mathop{\mathbf{r}}\varphi$" is not provable in PRA (nor in HA or PA), such that we need to resort to the weaker statement (2) with the internal $\exists$.

Comment: Intuitively, from a HA-proof of an existential statement we should _not_ be able to extract a witnessing number, just an _algorithm_ for computing a witnessing number.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Oh wow. This is catastrophic. Now I have to relearn everything I thought I learned about realizability  because apparently I misread the definitions from the start and nobody bothered to point out that unlike every other occurrence of pairings in computability here it matters very much what pairing is used. I'll be opening a question asking for further explanations — stay tuned.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Wait, are you sure? Troelstra's *Metamathematical Investigations of Intuitionistic Arithmetic and Analysis* (1973) ¶3.2.2 (p. 189) seems to use the same definition as I give (pairing is defined at ¶1.3.9(B) (p. 23)), and soundness is stated for it at ¶3.2.4. Similar definition in van Oosten's [*Realizability: a historical essay*](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0960129502003626), ¶2.2–2.3. Where is there a substantially different definition?

Comment: Yes; perhaps I should stress that in a strong metatheory like IZF or ZFC or even HA + "Turing machines which HA-provably terminate actually terminate", we do have the strong form of the soundness theorem with the external existential quantification even for the "sloppy" definition. The difference is visible only in weak metatheories like PRA, HA or PA. I think most works set in the context of an arbitrary untyped PCA get it right, as there the only pairing function $S \times S \to S$ which comes to mind is the appropriate version of Church pairs.

Comment: At the expense of one top-level implication, we can also get the "sloppy" definition to work in weak metatheories: PRA proves that for every formula $\varphi$, if HA proves $\varphi$ then there is a number $n$ such that HA proves $\overline{n} \mathop{\mathbf{r}}\, (\top \Rightarrow \varphi)$.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Ah, OK, I misread what you were saying (I thought you were saying that (2) doesn't work with HA as theory, but you mean it doesn't with HA as *meta*theory). You're not claiming there's anything wrong with what I wrote, just that the standard definition of arithmetical realizability (as in Kleene, Troelstra and others) can be altered so that proving soundness of realizability works in HA. But then (if I'm not mistaken) we lose the ability to prove the disjunction property and existence property of realizability as [it must be](https://mathoverflow.net/q/413659/17064).

Comment: That being said, maybe there's something fishy in what Troelstra writes: in ¶3.2.20(i) (p. 196) of *op.cit.* (= ‘Metamathematical Investigations…’) he uses the soundness of realizability to show that “HA+ECT₀ is consistent relative to HA”, which is a misleading way to state it at best if the proof only works in a theory that proves HA consistent in the first place.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Yes, indeed, on all points you raised in your two comments. :-) (That the altered definition doesn't prove the disjunction and the existence property is not a big issue to me. We need a variant of the standard Kleene definition anyway. All versions of realizability are beautiful)

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt If you think all versions of realizability are beautiful (and I agree), I suppose I don't need to run an ad for [this question I recently posted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/463183/17064). 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\let\T\mathrm\def\kr{\mathrel{\mathbf r}}$Let me first answer a slightly modified question:

> **Proposition:** For any sentence $\phi$, the following are equivalent:
>
> - There exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\T{PA}\vdash\overline n\kr\phi$.
> - $\T{HA+ECT_0+MP}\vdash\phi$.

The right-to-left direction follows from $\T{HA+MP}\subseteq\T{PA}$ and the fact that we can find explicit realizers in $\T{HA+MP}$ for each consequence of $\T{HA+ECT_0+MP}$.

On the other hand, assume that $\T{PA}\vdash\overline n\kr\phi$. The formula $x\kr\phi$ is almost negative, hence it is equivalent to a negative formula $\psi(x)$ in $\T{HA+MP}$. Then $\T{PA}\vdash\psi(\overline n)$, hence $\T{HA}$ proves its double negation translation. However, negative formulas are $\T{HA}$-provably equivalent to their double negation translations. Thus, $\T{HA}\vdash\psi(\overline n)$, $\T{HA+MP}\vdash\overline n\kr\phi$, and (by the result you quote) $\T{HA+ECT_0+MP}\vdash\phi$.

For the actual question you asked:

> **Proposition:** For any sentence $\phi$, $\T{PA}\vdash\exists x\,(x\kr\phi)$ if and only if $\T{HA+ECT_0+MP+SLEM}\vdash\phi$, where SLEM denotes the *sentential* law of excluded middle: the schema $\chi\lor\neg\chi$ for sentences $\chi$.

Left-to-right: continuing the argument above, $\T{PA}\vdash\exists x\,(x\kr\phi)$ implies that $\T{HA}$ proves the double negation translation of $\exists x\,\psi(x)$, which is equivalent to $\neg\neg\exists x\,\psi(x)$. Thus,
$$\T{HA+MP}\vdash\neg\neg\exists x\,(x\kr\phi).$$
Since $\exists x\,(x\kr\phi)$ is a sentence, this implies
$$\T{HA+MP+SLEM}\vdash\exists x\,(x\kr\phi).$$
By point 1 of your quoted result, this means
$$\T{HA+MP+SLEM+ECT_0}\vdash\phi.$$

For the right-to-left direction, it suffices to show
$$\T{PA}\vdash\exists x\,\bigl(x\kr(\chi\lor\neg\chi)\bigr).$$
It follows easily from the definition that
$$\T{HA}\vdash\exists x\,(x\kr\neg\chi)\leftrightarrow\neg\exists x\,(x\kr\chi).$$
Thus, using the law of excluded middle, PA proves that either $\chi$ has a realizer, or it does not, in which case anything is a realizer of $\neg\chi$. In both cases, we obtain a realizer of $\chi\lor\neg\chi$.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect such a clean characterization! And I also had never realized that SLEM is so different from LEM, and I am amazed that it does not contradict ECT₀. Do you know if HA+SLEM (with or without MP and/or ECT₀) has appeared in the literature before?

Comment: Yes, I’m sure these are well known. I’m not sure though what is a standard abbreviation for SLEM. Concerning consistency, note that if $T$ is *any* consistent theory in predicate intuitionistic logic, then $T+\mathrm{SLEM}$ is consistent by simple propositional reasoning (in fact, $T+\mathrm{SLEM}\vdash\phi$ iff $T\vdash\neg\neg\phi$).