# What are these non-classical versions of ZFC defined by realizability?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, constructive-mathematics, realizability

See *[Kleene realizability in Peano arithmetic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323964/kleene-realizability-in-peano-arithmetic)* for a similar question, but about PA instead of ZFC.

In the context of [constructive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory), consider two ways of defining realizability.

The first is $\Vdash$, which is just the set theoretic version of [Kleene's realizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realizability#Example:_Kleene%27s_1945-realizability). The $\Vdash$ relation is defined at [*Realizability for Constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory*](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Realizability-for-Constructive-Zermelo-Fraenkel-Set-Rathjen/1d3003b1d18a3c8389ebaddff63883a82cf5772a), "Definition: 4.1".

The second is $\Vdash_{rt}$ "realizability with truth". It is defined at [*The Disjunction and Related Properties for Constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory*](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/tklr.pdf), "Definition 5.2".

The main difference is that, in every subcase, $e \Vdash_{rt} \phi$ also asserts that $\phi$ is true. For example, $e \Vdash \phi \implies \psi$ means $$\forall f. (f \Vdash \phi \implies ef \Vdash \psi)$$ whereas $e \Vdash_{rt} \phi \implies \psi$ means $$(\phi^\circ \implies \psi^\circ) \land \forall f. (f \Vdash_{rt} \phi \implies ef \Vdash_{rt} \psi)$$

For example, if our meta-theory is ZFC, the statement *"all real numbers are computable"* is realized according to $\Vdash$ whereas the statement *"not all real numbers are computable"* is realized according to $\Vdash_{rt}$, but *"there exists a real number that is not computable"* is realized according to neither.

Now consider the following four theories:

|  | Known witness | Witness exists |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anti-classical | $\text{ZFC}_1 = \{\phi : \exists e. \text{ZFC} \vdash (\overline e \Vdash \phi) \}$ | $\text{ZFC}_2 = \{\phi : \text{ZFC} \vdash (\exists e. e \Vdash \phi) \}$ |
| Realizable with truth | $\text{ZFC}_3 = \{\phi : \exists e. \text{ZFC} \vdash (\overline e \Vdash_{rt} \phi) \}$ | $\text{ZFC}_4 = \{\phi : \text{ZFC} \vdash (\exists e. e \Vdash_{rt} \phi) \}$ |

Usually realizability is considered with an intuitionistic meta-theory, but it works just as well with ZFC.

My question is **how do you nicely axiomatize them**, as was done in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/323988/65915) for Peano arithmetic?

---

Some observations:

- $\text{ZFC}_1$ and $\text{ZFC}_3$ have the [disjunction property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties) and the other nice properties from the second paper. $\text{ZFC}_2$ and $\text{ZFC}_4$ do not because they prove LEM for $\Sigma^0_1$ sentences.
- They are definitely recursively enumerable, since we're just searching for proofs in ZFC.
- $$IZF \subset \text{ZFC}_1 \subset \text{ZFC}_2$$ $$IZF \subset \text{ZFC}_3 \subset \text{ZFC}_4 \subset \text{ZFC}$$
- Since ZFC has the axiom of choice, the four theories all prove the [axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) (and thus are not just $\text{IZF}$).
- $\text{ZFC}_1$ (and thus also $\text{ZFC}_2$) proves [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%27s_thesis_%28constructive_mathematics%29), which is incompatible with LEM.
- $\text{ZFC}_3$ (and thus also $\text{ZFC}_4$) proves $\lnot \phi$ for statements $\phi$ such that $\lnot \phi$ is a theorem of $\text{ZFC}$.

Comment: Did you read McCarty's 1986 papers [“Realizability and recursive set theory”](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072%2886%2990050-3) and [“Subcountability under realizability”](https://doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1093636613) and section 3.5 of van Oosten's book *Realizability: An Introduction to its Categorical Side* (2008)? I don't think they have an answer as precise as you ask, but they certainly provide some important background.

Comment: These results are often known as "Characterization Theorems". There are several examples of these but, as far as I can tell, there are quite a few that are missing. At least in the sense of "never explicitly stated".

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais do you think it might be an open problem? Like Gro-Tsen brought to my attention this has been studied for a while.

Comment: Well, coming up with a meaningful axiomatization always requires artistry. I don't think "open problem" is a good description of this process.

Comment: Is it obvious that you actually get a realizer for countable choice? This isn't clear to me at all.

Comment: @JamesHanson oh I wouldn't say it's obvious. It follows from theorem 10.1 in the first paper. The realizer is pretty straight forward though, you just extract the function from your existential proof. Actually, for $\Vdash$ you might not even need any choice in the meta-theory .